# Access gateway/profile params/variables in Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

To get variables from a user we call `user_data(user var variable_name)`.

```
<include>
    <user id="1000">
        <variables>
            <variable name="custom_variable" value="test"/>
        </variables>
   </user>
</include>
```

We call in a way like that:

```
<action application="set" data="variable_name=${user_data(${caller_id_number}@${domain_name} var custom_variable)}"/>
```

But how to do the same with a gateway?

```
<include>
    <gateway name="custom_gateway">
        <param name="custom_param" value="test"/>
    </gateway>
</include>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible.

FS application set is ['Set a channel variable for the channel calling the application'](http://goo.gl/yRnwjv) while gateway data is somewhere in the sofia module. However, [there is a way to list gateway data from console](http://goo.gl/Y41UGK). Have a look at [sofia_gateway_data_function](http://goo.gl/zi1RGd) in the source code, hope it sheds some light on what you need to do. Good luck!